# Script Component not Being detected by Vuforia's Default Trackable Event Handler Script

Tags: unity, android, 3d, vuforia

I have a Script Component named `Start` inside a `GameObject` named `StartSpawn` and I am trying to run a function from `Start` when the target is found but Unity/Visual Studio is not detecting the `Start` script component. I even tried restarting both Unity and Visual Studio to only worsen the problem. When I opened both programs again and inspecting the code, the code I added was deleted and the script `DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs` was back to its original code. Btw, the function I'm calling to Instantiates a Prefab.

Here's the code inside the `DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs`:

```
protected virtual void OnTrackingFound()
{
    if (mTrackableBehaviour)
    {
        var rendererComponents = mTrackableBehaviour.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
        var colliderComponents = mTrackableBehaviour.GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);
        var canvasComponents = mTrackableBehaviour.GetComponentsInChildren<Canvas>(true);
        //test
        Start summoner = GetComponentInChildren<Start>();

        // Enable rendering:
        foreach (var component in rendererComponents)
            component.enabled = true;

        // Enable colliders:
        foreach (var component in colliderComponents)
            component.enabled = true;

        // Enable canvas':
        foreach (var component in canvasComponents)
            component.enabled = true;

        //test spawn
        summoner.OnAppear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Vuforia, I am giving few tricks to you for instantiate object:

1. make a script `CustomTrackableEventHandler.cs`
2. add on image target in place of  `DefaultTrackableEventHandler`.
3. copy code from `DefaultTrackableEventHandler` to `CustomTrackableEventHandler`.
4. add variable `public Gameobject prefab;`
5. add function in `OnTrackingFound()` and `OnTrackingLost()` as per this:

   ```
   public void InstantiateObject(){
       Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
   }

   public void DestroyObject(){
       Destroy(this.gameobject);
   }
   ```

This is just basic logic; if you want to learn advanced logic, let me know and I will help you.